# Ruby - instance variable as class variable

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I have a class:

```
class Foo

  def self.test
    @test
  end

  def foo
    @test = 1
    bar
  end

  private

  def bar
    @test = 2
  end
end

object = Foo.new.foo
Foo.test

# => nil
```

The only way I could get it to output '2' is by making `@test` a class variable. Is there any other way around using the instance variable and being able to display it with `Foo.test`?

Comment: `Foo.test` which is a class method has no access to instance variables.

Comment: What's your real goal? You're using different objects, so they obviously don't have access to the same instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve, and why. Here's an example with a "class instance variable". It might be what you're looking for:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :test
  end

  attr_accessor :test

  def foo
    @test = 1
    bar
  end

  private

  def bar
    Foo.test = 2
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.foo
p foo.test
#=> 1
p Foo.test
#=> 2
```

Comment: You commented at the same time with me lol. Well that was the purpose of the question, how to avoid using @@ but having the same result. My version is a little bit different though.